# Open a file and load it into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have made a script to open a file and save it in a variable. But when I use this script it doesn't works.

```
 from tkinter import filedialog
    global file_path
    # Open and return file path
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("mov files", "*.png"), 
    ("mp4", "*.mp4"), ("wmv", "*.wmv"), ("avi", "*.avi")))
    l1 = gui(gui, text = "File path: " + file_path).pack()
```

Can anyone say a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? What happens that shouldn't? What doesn't happen that should?

Comment: Also, what is that `gui()` function that you pass itself to?

Comment: "doesn't works" is a useless phrase. If the code you posted is accurate you should be getting indentation errors. Is that what it's doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to do. Are trying to make a string variable with the selected file path in it?

If so, then here's your first problem; you haven't imported tkinter yet, you need to make a window (and hide it using [windowname].withdraw()). Second of all, on the last line when you are trying to assign l1, you are trying to assign it to something that doesn't exist. The pack function isn't for variables.

I've made a short little script with what I think you're trying to do:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select A File", filetypes = (("mov files", "*.png"), 
    ("mp4", "*.mp4"), ("wmv", "*.wmv"), ("avi", "*.avi")))
l1 = "File path: " + file_path
```